# regular expression cut string between

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with one regular expression

My reg exp. is

```
          SELECT REX.[Value],RS.LogEntryId FROM ReportServerReplica.[dbo].[ExecutionLogStorage] RS 
          OUTER APPLY [WarehouseMgmt].RegExpMatches(RS.[Parameters], '(?<=User=).+?(?=&)') REX
          WHERE RS.[Parameters] IS NOT NULL
```

It works when i have examples like

```
&User=admin&Format:isnull=true&R
```

but it doesn't work for

```
&User=admin
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in this way as well that will match untill `&` is found after *User=*.

```
(?<=User=)[^&]+
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/cN4mB0/2)

output:

```
admin
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    User=                    'User='
  )                        end of look-behind
  [^&]+                    any character except: '&' (1 or more times)
```

Comment: And note that, `[^&]+` matches newline characters also.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$` inside the positive lookahead with the alternation operator. `$` called end of the line anchor.

```
(?<=User=).+?(?=&|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cN4mB0/1)